# Accessing data from async function - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, async-await

I'm trying to query a data service and use the json response to create a table with React. I have the following async function that creates a list of the json response (this part works as intended):

```
export const service_query = async function(url){
  const resp = await fetch(url);
    const result = await resp.json();
  const features = result.features;
  const features_list = []
  for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++){
    features_list.push(features[0].attributes)
  }
  return features_list;
}
```

I'm not too familiar with async functions and am having trouble accessing the data. I've checked similar questions on here and haven't gotten a clear answer. My research shows that I need to need to call the async function with an await but that can only be done inside another async function, which once again returns a promise when called without await. I'm stuck in this loop...

```
import './App.css';
import { service_query } from './Utils';
import Table from './Table';

function App() {
  const url = "[url goes here]";
  const data_values = service_query(url)
  const headers = Object.keys(data_values[0])
  const content = Object.values(data_values)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Test</h1>  
        <div className="container">
          <Table theadData={headers} tbodyData={content}/>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've tried the following but this once again means I can't access the data and get the promise:

```
 const getData = async() => {
    const data_values = await service_query(url)
    return data_values
  };
```

I also tried the following, but can't access data_values outside the function and assigning the entire thing to a variable returns a promise again:

```
  service_query(url).then((data) => {
    const data_values = data
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make async calls within `useEffect`, and update the response with `useState`. Something like this:

```
const url = 'some url'
function App() {
  const [headers, setHeaders] = useState(null);
  const [content, setContent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    service_query(url).then(response => {
       setHeaders(response[0]);
       setContent(response);
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Test</h1>  
        <div className="container">
          {!!headers && !!content && (
            <Table theadData={headers} tbodyData={content}/>
          )}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div> 
  );
}
```

Comment: @Andy true, I will update the answer

Comment: This works (finally!) - for my understanding, can I ask why you added the following: {!!headers && !!content && (

Comment: @ArcPie_22 glad to hear it works. that condition is to make sure the Table is not rendered before  data is returned from server. Initial values are null, if Table uses them before checking their value, you will get type errors.